# Insert MySQL Query with use of concat

Tags: mysql, database, insert

Im trying to insert a query to my database using a name in a variable and also using a name in the values. So i want to make it in to 1 name.

Here is an example

```
SET @name = "This is my";
INSERT INTO mytable (id, name)
VALUES (1, @name + "Test Query");
```

So, This query should then insert a row with id 1 and name "This is my Test Query" But it gives me an error. **Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'Test Query'**

Comment: what is the length of name used in table? nad also you can use `CONCATE()` function for accomplish this requirment.

Answer (score 7):

You can't use `@name + "Test Query"` syntax instead you shoud use `concat()` mysql function see here for more info:http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-concat-function.php

```
SET @name = "This is my";
INSERT INTO `names` (id, name)
VALUES (1, concat(@name, 'Test Query'));
```

also make sure that your id is not autoincreament if it is then no need to pass id number in your query like this

```
INSERT INTO `names` (name)
VALUES (concat(@name, 'Test Query'));
```

Comment: Thank you, I was thinking about the concat function but i was not sure if it was possible to use it in an insert query. Anyway this worked for me. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

i found no error in `sql`.. it executed without error..

```
DECLARE @name as varchar(100)  
DECLARE @mytable  as table ( id int, [name] varchar(100))  

SET @name = 'This is my';

INSERT INTO @mytable (id, name)
VALUES (1, @name + 'Test Query');

Select * from @mytable
```